# VSTO MS Word 2003 add-in causes error "Word experienced a serious error the last time the add-in 'XYZ' was opened"

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

An add-in we make is causing the above problem on a Windows 2003 server, without any obvious cause. Both Word and the add-in appear to work correctly yet the message comes up and Word wants to disable the add-in.  I have run with VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0 and no messages come up. On my machine (XP) the problem does not occur.

Any suggestions as to what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that it's working fine on your WinXP machine, I advise you to download and install the [VSTO Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=46B6BF86-E35D-4870-B214-4D7B72B02BF9&displaylang=en) and run the installed VSTO Troubleshooter application to assert if any dependency is missing on the Windows 2003 Server machine. If no errors are found by the troubleshooter check any third-parties dependencies that may exist.

By the way, welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks

I don't VSTO troubleshooter will show a problem. It has worked previously on the 2003 server, then stopped. 

How do I check 3rd party dependencies?

Comment: @TTT, I assumed it never worked on the Windows 2003 machine. If you haven't made any changes to the add-in then I have no idea of what may cause that error.